# BroadcastReceiver for Android Calendar events (2018)

Tags: java, android, calendar, intentfilter

This question is indeed a duplicate to [Listen for new calendar events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21168766/listen-for-new-calendar-events)

I have been trying to register the BroadcastReceiver with the way specified in the link, however, my app couldn't receive any broadcast when I modified the phone's calendar.

I also tried to add it through IntentFilter instead of through the AndroidManifest

```
    filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PROVIDER_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(calendarReceiver,filter);
```

still no luck getting it to receive the broadcast. Did I miss anything or listening to calendar's changes cannot be done anymore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must add the scheme and and authority for calendar events:

```
filter.addDataScheme("content");
filter.addDataAuthority("com.android.calendar", null);
```

A complete example of listening for calendar changes would be:

CalendarReceiver.java

```
public class CalendarReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("example", "Calendar changed (or the phone just booted)");
    }
}
```

Activity.java

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_PROVIDER_CHANGED);
filter.addDataScheme("content");
filter.addDataAuthority("com.android.calendar", null);
registerReceiver(new CalendarReceiver(), filter);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I hasn't found any solutions mentioning scheme which indeed solved my problem.

Comment: Note that the subscription will only last as long as the lifetime of the context on which registerReeiver is called. You may want to use JobService instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49619666/2019549